# How to get the year information as string value?

Tags: c#

I have a content like below from that I want to select only the year information as string values.

Given this input string:

> For example, one of the major problems is that the observer dynamics
>   are assumed to be faster than that of the state feedback controller,
>   which will cause numerical difficulty (Astrom and Wittenmark, 1997).
>   What’s more, when the process constraints are activated, the
>   significant deterioration of closed-loop control performance will be
>   clearly witnessed as kind of nonlinearity is dominating the control
>   system (Tenny, Rawlings, and Wright, 2004). Therefore, it is necessary
>   to develop methods capable of tackling the above problems.

I would like to extract `1997` and `2004`.

Notes:

1. Year information occurs only in four digits
2. Most probably it ends with full stop (period) or close bracket
3. It may occur at any place within the paragraph

Comment: "most probably" doesn't help. You'd need something more definitive than that.

Comment: @KshitijMehta +1. And maybe not all the 4 digits ends up with a bracket is actually a 'Year'.

Comment: I think you'll want to use a regex for this...

Comment: I have some datum which contains the reference book details and author name like (Deepak G. 2012. Wireless communication Networks) based on this i get a author first name as a stringauthorname to compare contents with references. Now i want to compare the same with two condition Author name as well as year information as string  values.

Comment: string[] strAuthorsPart = strPara.Split('.');
string[] strAuthorslist = strAuthorsPart[0].Split(',');
string[] strAuthor = strAuthorslist[0].Split(' '); How to i get the year information too for comparision?

Answer (score 1):

```
var years = Regex.Matches(input, @"\D(\d{4})\D")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd suggest you the following regex.

```
 ((19|20)\d{2})
```

or

```
 \b((19|20)\d{2})\b
```

In .NET there is also support for named groups so the following is also a convenient way to match the pattern.

```
\b(?<Years>(19|20)\d{2})\b
```

Note: This regex searchs for four digits and first two must be `19` or `20`.
If there can be earlier years you can include them

```
\b(?<Years>(17|18|19|20)\d{2})\b
```

Comment: I'm guessing the sample provided was just that... a sample. You should be more inclusive than years which start only with 19 or 20.

Answer (score 0):

Are your years limited at all? Meaning, nothing older than 1900? Or 1800? This will let you be slightly more precise.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@" (19|20)\d\d\))") 

MatchCollection years = regex.Matches(your_input);
```

I *think* that regex will match any dates in the 1900s or 2000s, that have a preceding space, and end with a ).

You can then iterate over the MatchCollection getting all instances that matched.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `\d\d\d\d[\)\]\.]` regex.

This searches for all 4 digit numbers that end with a `)` or `]` or `.`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex expressions. Something like `^[12][0-9]{3}$`  will validate your year.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, "^[12][0-9]{3}$");
```

Comment: Good pattern but get rid of `^` and `$`. String is longer than 4 symbols and the pattern may occur at any place of the line. Further, the OP doesn't want to validate, he wants to retrieve.